# Cannot stitch images

Tags: opencv

I want to stitch together 2 images using OpenCV's stitching.cpp [sample program](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp)
When I attempt to stitch the images, I get "Can't stitch images, error code = 1" depending on what images I attempt to stitch together.
For example, the following 2 example images I got online are successfully stitched together:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
But these 2 images get me the error:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is no overlap whatesoever and they are blurred as well, take better pictures with more overlap. Even as a human, i'm finding hard to understand where the images should be stitched.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there had to be overlap. Thought any 2 images could be stitched from edge to edge. (That's really what I care about). I tried stitching images that had more overlap this time with no error but much of the picture came out as black blank space. Are there guidelines to how much overlap is required?

Comment: The more the merrier, usually =) depending on the algorithm. Probably openCV is around 70% for good results, but your mileage may vary! If you just want to merge two images by its edge (basically if i understand correctly, pic1 800x600, pic2 800x600 --> get a 1600x600 img ?), then openCV is a bit of an overkill, try something like CImg for example

Comment: Thanks, I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055085/opencv-image-stitching-does-not-work-properly I try to have overlap in my sample images, but still cannot get the output correctly.