# OpenCV Stitcher library is outputting a squished image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I am working on a program that will stitch together images from a UAV, I cannot seem to get any of the stitching methods that I can find online to work. most notably the simple Stitcher class that openCV has. These are my two input images are the last two and the result is the first image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOtRA.jpg

So obviously that is not right but I do not know where I went wrong as it is just a simple call to the stitcher.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Load the images
//Mat image1 = imread(argv[2]);
//Mat image2 = imread(argv[1]);

VideoCapture cap("vid.mp4");

vector<Mat> Vimg;
Mat result;

cout << "Grabbing Images" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Grabbing Frame" << i << endl;
    Mat temp;
    cap.read(temp);
    Vimg.push_back(temp);
    imwrite("image" + to_string(i) + ".jpg", temp);
    for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
        cap.grab();
}

Stitcher stitch = Stitcher::createDefault();
cout << "Starting Stitching" << endl;
stitch.stitch(Vimg, result);

imwrite("result.jpg", result);

}
```

Comment: See if the keypoint matching is working correctly. Most of the times, that is the problem. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30055085/1586200).

Comment: If I am using the build in stitching function how would I go about seeing if its working correctly or not?

Comment: See what kind of keypoint detector and descriptor it uses? My guess is that it uses `BRISK` (I may be wrong). If it does, then write a separate code which detects keypoints using BRISK, then match them and see if that's the fault. You can also write your own code for basic stitching, as shown [here](http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/). Before all this, it may be helpful to download some simple images and see if those work, then move on to your images. You will discover the fault eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i realized that stitching is not what I want exactly, so I have to create my own algorithm to do what I want.

Comment: I was actually going to ask you that next, since the images you have shown to us through that link look different.

Comment: Yes originally, I was just trying to get the stitching working with some sample images from a UAV, but realized that's not what I wanted so I started to rework the problem with thermal images, as in my new post.